# AngularJS service writing style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's (schematically) the kind of code I'm using to define a service in AngularJS:

```
.factory('MyService', function() {

    var prv = {
            // Private stuff I don't want to expose
    };

    var pub = {
        // Public stuff - Will read & write prv above
    };

    return pub;
})
```

As you might guess, the goal is to isolate the private vars and functions the service needs to work with and only return the public part (in every AngularJS example I've seen so far, the factory function returns an object that contains both some data and the functions that manipulates that data -which, IMHO, isn't right.)

This works quite well and I never had any problems so far, but I'm wondering: since the prv object is inside an anonymous function and is not used outside that function, is it safe? Or is it at risk of being destroyed by -say- garbage collection or some other behind-the-scene process in the interpreter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no risk of garbage collection as the service/factory is a singleton and once created will live for the lifespan of the application. Also there is no real need for the prv object as anything created within the service that is not part of the return object (`pub` in your example) is inherently private, because it is not exposed via the return object.

My services/factories are typically structured like so:

```
.factory('MyService', function() {
    function doStuff(){doPrivateStuff();}
    function doPrivateStuff(){}

    return {
        doServiceStuff: doStuff
    };
});
```